# what is antlr3 and why is it referenced by default in a VS2012 MVC4 project?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012

I have created a new MVC4 project in VS2012, and there's a new reference I've never seen nor heard of, googling seems to land me on the occasional syntax or grammar post. Can you now write code generation in VS2010 with something besides T4? Can you write in multiple languages in the same project if you have one defined in the project? what is it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The WebGrease package (http://nuget.org/packages/WebGrease), which the MVC 4 templates make use of, is dependent on this binary.  It doesn't have anything to do with T4, multiple languages in the project, or anything else IDE-related.

Comment: In an ASP.NET Web API project, can we remove this antlr3.dll from our references?

Comment: Most probably as you won't need any webpages.